# How do I get the dereferenced type of a pointer type in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

Like this:

```
template <typename Tptr>
struct Test
{
    Test(Tptr) {}
    typedef decltype(*Tptr) T;
    T dereferencedType;
};

int i;
Test t(&i); // t.dereferencedType is type int
```

I'm looking to get the type of *Tptr dereferenced.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer

Comment: Why not change `Test(Tptr)` to `Test(Tptr*)` so that `Tptr` is the dereferenced type as-is?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that might be better. What if I then need the type of a pointer to that type? So in other words the opposite of remove_pointer?

Comment: A pointer to type `T` is of course `T*`

Comment: Of course, silly me

Comment: @Zebrafish "*So in other words the opposite of remove_pointer*" - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer